# How to get the ability to change the author of a post

Tags: posts, author

Recently it has become impossible to change the author of any posts on my blog. I am administrator off the blog. Other admins have the same problem.

It doesn't seem code related; I've checked out older versions in git off which I'm sure it worked, but the option is still gone.

I've already checked my user capabilities, I have the "edit_others_posts" capability.

I have disabled all plugins, but that didn't help.

Is there some setting that is stored as a user setting that might by accident have been changed?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have enabled Author from Screen Options in Post area?

You can check the screenshot attached below for more info.

[image: Enabling Author from Screen options WordPress]

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown only shows when there are multiple users with author rights available.

I had only my own admin account and several subscribers locally, in which case apparently the dropdown doesn't render at all. In production, there is a different bug that has the side effect that the author dropdown also doesn't render.

Comment: Jasper.  This isn't actually an answer.  You should add this as commentary to your question or as a comment to the provided answer.